# Filter by computed value on Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails and I have a scenario where the user can apply several different filters to, let's say, a user table.
I have created `scopes` for each filter and apply them to my query depending if the filter is present or not, like:

```
  scope :with_age, ->(age) {
    where({age: age})
  }

  scope :with_country, ->(country_id) {
    includes(:country).where({country: {id: country_id} })
  }
```

The problem now is that product wants to be able to filter by a computed property. As an example, let's say they want to filter by user generation (whatever). So I would need something like the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT *, CASE
        WHEN u2.age < 10 THEN 'Z'
        WHEN u2.age >= 10 AND u2.age <20 THEN 'MILENIALS'
        ELSE 'WHATEVER'
    END as generation
    FROM users u2
    -- here I want to apply another filters that were passed to not calculate this for the whole table
) as u1
WHERE generation = :generation_filtered
```

Now, is there a way I can build this query using `ActiveRecord` methods so I can still use my pre built scopes? Kinda lost on that.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The example I gave above does not reflect what I actually need. Sorry for that. Imagine actually the user has a score based on how many questions he has asked and how many replies he had replied. Both those infos are stored in a user column. So the query I *actually* need would be something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT *, CASE
        WHEN u2.questions < u2.answers THEN 'TEACHER'
        WHEN u2.questions = u2.answers THEN 'NEUTRAL'
        WHEN u2.questions > u2.answers THEN 'APPRENTICE'
    END as user_score
    FROM users u2
    -- here I want to apply another filters that were passed to not calculate this for the whole table
) as u1
WHERE user_score = :score
```

Comment: You could use [`from`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from) and have that as the users table with the computed property which you can apply any scope on, but that wouldn't look well and might result confusing. In Rails >= 7.1 you could use `with` but with the same problem.  Or you could use something like Postgres generated columns and skip that trouble of using a subquery as the column will always be there for you to use it.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for the answer... Yes I have suggested the generated columns approach but db managers are relutant on adding a new column on the table... so im just checking this other option... Will try with the from to see how it is like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this by defining the age ranges for each generation and then just picking the specific age range in the scope:

```
GENERATIONS = { 'Z' => (..10), 'MILLENNIALS' => (11...20), 'WHATEVER' => (20..) }

scope :by_generation, ->(generation) { where(age: GENERATIONS[generation]) }
```

Which then can be used like this:

```
MyModel.by_generation('Z')
```

And, of course, this scope can be chained like this:

```
MyModel.by_generation('Z').with_country('BR')
```

---

**UPDATE**

The problem from your updated question can be solved with the same pattern:

```
SCORE_CONDITIONS = {
  'TEACHER'    => 'users.questions < users.answers',
  'NEUTRAL'    => 'users.questions = users.answers',
  'APPRENTICE' => 'users.questions > users.answers'
}

scope by_score, ->(score) { where(SCORE_CONDITIONS[score]) }
```

Which can be called like this

```
User.by_score('TEACHER')
```

Comment: That's neat. Hats off

Comment: @spickermann thanks for the answer... Hate when this happens but the example I provided does not reflect exactly my use case... I added another example now reflecting exactly what I need and I think your solution is not applicable on that... Is it? Thanks again and sorry for that

Comment: @JoãoMenighin I updated my answer to address your updated question.

Comment: Ok, I didnt grasp the concept on the first example. Now it makes totally sense. Thanks!!